# How to interate ZipFile content in alphabetic order?

Tags: java, zip

I have a large `.zip` archive with thousands of files. How can I iterate them in a specific order (eg alphabetic ascending)?

```
try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(archive)) {
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        var file = entries.nextElement();
        //...
    }
}
```

I found streaming could be an option. But is it possible also without streaming?

```
List<? extends ZipEntry> list = zip.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ZipEntry::getName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Have you tried using zip.stream() and sorting the stream according to your desired order?

Comment: Yes, see my edit. But I'd prefer sorting without having to run through the stream explicit.

Comment: Can't you just to list the enumeration and sort like that? https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-sort-an-enumeration/

Comment: I mean, you can always sort your Enumeration by converting it to a list and sorting it with Collections.sort. But that does not really feel better than the streaming imo.

Comment: You can get all the entries and use `Collections.sort()` or any other of the multitude of ways to sort objects in Java. There's no concept of "zip sorting", so your question boils down to "how do I sort objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ZipFile specific way of sorting the ZipFile's entries or "reading" the ZipFile's content ordered. The only reference to ordering in the ZipFile Javadoc is when using ZipFile.stream.

In that case the entries "[...] appear in the Stream in the order they appear in the central directory of the ZIP file."

So you are left with the usual approaches when ordering/sorting in java:

Either use the stream() method to fetch a stream, order it and do your logic:

```
zip.stream()
   .sorted( Comparator.comparing( ZipEntry::getName ) ) // define your order
   .forEach( this::doStuff ); // do your logic, in this example it is a method in this class
```

or convert the enumeration to a collection and sort the collection, for example like

```
List< ? extends ZipEntry > entries = Collections.list( zip.entries() );
entries.sort( Comparator.comparing( ZipEntry::getName ) ); // define your order
for (ZipEntry entry : entries) {
    doStuff(entry);
}
```